# If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n} = 0$, then $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} =$

Tags: calculus

Let $\langle a_{n}\rangle$ be a sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n} = 0$, Then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = $

$\bf{My\; Try:}$ I have assume $\displaystyle a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}$, Then $\displaystyle a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$

Now I did not understand how can I solve it.

Answer given as $ = 1$.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is not $1$. All the $a_i$ can vanish.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$ can be compared to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$$ by means of: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\right) \left( \frac{n}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n} \right) = 1$$

Which means that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$$ converges to zero, then the first limit must converge to zero as well, since otherwise the limit would diverge. Finally this last sequence converges to the same limit as $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. This is a standard exercise in Real Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$ then for $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N$ large enough that for $n\ge N$ we have $\lvert a_{n}\rvert<\epsilon$. So if we choose M large we can say the following:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{N}+a_{N+1}+...+a_{N+M}}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}}\right|  & =\left|\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{N}}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}}+\frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_{N+M}}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}}\right| \\
& \le\left|\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{N}}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}}\right|+\frac{\lvert a_{N+1}\rvert+...+\lvert a_{N+M}\rvert}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}}\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{M\epsilon}{\sqrt{(N+M)(N+M+1)}} \\
& =\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{(\frac{N}{M}+1)(\frac{N+1}{M}+1)}}<\frac{3}{2}\epsilon\\
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Part 1: Prove that if $a_n \to 0$ then
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \to 0$$

You might want to check out Cesaro sums.

Part 2: 
$$ 0 \leq \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right|$$

QED

PS: The answer is not 1.

Comment: Be careful here. If the sum of the $a_k$'s is negative, the inequality is false.

Comment: You can correct this by placing absolute values around your sums $$0\le \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \left|  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right| \le \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right|$$

Comment: Usually that doesn't work, but in this case since the constant is positive and not inside of the sum, it is ok.

Comment: Forgot to add the ||. Thanks for the correction. I have made the necessary changes.